# Elastisearch 7.17 installed but not displaying as option to select in Admin Panel Stores->Configuration->Catalog

Tags: magento2.4

I am running into issues when upgrading from 2.3.2 to 2.4.  Following the documentation from https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade.html?lang=en

1. All the pre-requisites installed to perform the upgrade
2. Elastisearch 7.17 has been installed. I know Adobe mentions that Elastisearch 7.6.x is supported by Magento 2.4.0 but the documentation does list Elastisearch 7.x can be used for the upgrade.
   [image]
3. In Admin Panel->Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Search, I do not see Elastisearch 7.0+.
   [image]

Question: why don't I see Elastisearch 7.0+ in the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config indicates your site is still on Magento 2.3, you can check your Magento version in admin at the bottom right of the page.

Assume, you want to upgrade your Magento site to 2.4.0 Open Source, run the following command in the root directory:

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update && composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update

composer update

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as **accepted**. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.
And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.

Comment: Thank you Tu Van. I was following the Adobe documentation, which directed me to first update all the software e.g. PHP 7.4, Elastisearch 7.0 etc before performing the upgrade to 2.4.0.  You are recommending to first perform the upgrade and then update the software?

Comment: No, you have to update the software first, then perform the Magento upgrade. You only see the config change like your screenshot that showing **Elasticsearch 7** once you have done the upgrade Magento.

Comment: Thank you Tu Van. I will follow your advice.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If you have any issues, feel free to create a new post, or you also can hire me to support your Magento sites (or at least help you upgrade the Magento version).